# to check that string should not be empty

Tags: java, string

I am reading a csv file and I have to do a check where string should not be empty in the
text file  , i am using this approach

```
if (str == null || str.trim().length() == 0 ) {
            return false;
```

Now my text file contain the record like

```
AAA BBB CCC 

adr ytr tru

wsu eit ifd

wer ert ref
```

Now I am putting a break point in the piece of cose as I want to test the case of 
string is empty one so what should I need to do in the text file , shall I remove the row
as shown below please advise

```
AAA BBB CCC

adr ytr tru


wer ert ref
```

I am taking a complete string as input for ex Sting t = fhgfgffjfufjk

Comment: If you are reading line by line - then, Yes

Comment: Regardless of your issue first instead of str.trim().length() == 0  use str.isEmpty()

Comment: using jdk 1.5 and empty is not suppoerted

Comment: @Baadshah - `str.trim().length() == 0` is the proper usage. `isEmpty()` recognizes `space` as a `valid` character in the String.

Comment: @R.J i mean when reading file space in a string is valid right ?

Comment: @Baadshah - Agreed! But I really doubt, if the OP would check for that. Generally, its blank lines, OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @R.J we can't do anything,until OP respond on this :) move on.

Comment: IMO, the real question is: why would the `wsu eit ifd` line be deleted?

Comment: btw, OP, I think you are the only one who can answer "shall I remove the row as shown below".  You can and of course it is possible to do so.  However, "shall I remove" actually means whether it is correct to do so.  Only you know whether it is correct to ignore empty line or treat it as error.  No one can answer this for you.

Answer (score 1):

although using `str == null || str.trim().isEmpty()` is valid, you may consider using [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) which allow you to do:

```
if (StringUtils.isBlank(str))
```

for which, imho, is more readable.

Comment: "==" is ok when you comaring with null but compring with empty string he is using one more extra method than the available string  method equals() thats why i gave the answer like that is anything wrong in that

Comment: First, please add the comment under your question where the discussion is going on. Second, using `str.equals("")` method to do empty string verification has been always known to be no optimal solution. Third, in your answer, you said OP should use `equals()` instead of `== or something other operators`.  This doesn't align with what you said here.

Answer (score 0):

It might seem overkill at first glance, but I would go with [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) library for this. There also a number a additional methods very useful while working with strings. Far better to rely in a proven solution and don't try to reinvent.

It's very intuitive and easy to use:

```
String str
Boolean b = StringUtils.isEmpty(str);
```

Comment: using `isEmpty` is not going to work as OP is doing `trim().length()==0` which means string containing spaces should evalute true here.  `isEmpty()` returns false in such case.  As mentioned in my answer, OP should use `isBlank` instead

Comment: Fair enough, sometimes can get a bit confusing what someone means with "empty".

Comment: Same feeling there :P  Just happened that I have noticed his `trim()`.  `StringUtils.isEmpty()` is doubtless the right answer in most of common situations.

Answer (score -1):

why don't you try with **equals()** or **equlasIgnoreCase()** for checking string values instead of using "==" or something other operators ..

for comparing length of string ok